# Integrating factor for arbitrary first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading the section 'Integrating Factors'  from the book *Differential Equations Theory, Technique, and Practice by George F. Simmons.*

We want to find an integrating factor for any given first-order equation. The details are in the given images.

My doubt: It says that **Now we use the method of wishful thinking: We suppose not only that an integrating
factor $μ$ exists, but in fact that one exists that only depends on the variable $x$ (and not at
all on $y$ ).**

What is the guarantee that an integrating factor will exist which depends only on variable $x$ (or variable $y$)?

[image]

Comment: There is no guarantee that an integrating factor will exist which depends only on variable x. The author is making a choice. He is not proving the fact. You could say it's the simplest possible choice. There is no general method to find IF, and therefore, people make some extra assumptions to find a special kind of Integrating factor.

Comment: This is just a additional continuation of @James comment. If it is not a function of $~x~$, then we can not use this particular method.